# Count() return 0 instead of NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I have read the other questions and the answers don't seem to fix my situation. I have a table of company names and a table of activities associated with those companies.

I need to count the amount of activities in a specified date range, and return 0 if there are none. I also need to get the date of the last activity (even if it outside the specified date range).

I am using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, I have tried `ISNULL()` (although, how can it check if it's null if it doesn't exist?), I'm not sure where to go from here.

This is what I have:

```
SELECT       v_rpt_Company.Company_Name, COUNT(DISTINCT SO_Activity.SO_Activity_Recid) as touches, MAX(SO_Activity.Date_Entered) As lasttouch
FROM            v_rpt_Member LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Company_Team ON v_rpt_Member.Member_RecID = Company_Team.Member_RecID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         v_rpt_Company ON Company_Team.Company_RecID = v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         SO_Activity ON v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID = SO_Activity.Company_RecID
WHERE        (Company_Team.AcctMgr_Flag = 1) AND (v_rpt_Member.Member_ID = @member) AND ((SO_Activity.Last_Update >= CONVERT(datetime, @date_start, 101)) AND ( SO_Activity.Last_Update <= CONVERT(datetime, @date_end, 101))) 
GROUP BY v_rpt_Company.Company_Name
ORDER BY v_rpt_Company.Company_Name ASC,lasttouch DESC,touches DESC
```

**This is the final answer: (Thanks everyone)**

```
SELECT a.touches, a.name,b.lasttouch

FROM (

 SELECT       v_rpt_Company.Company_Name as name,
COUNT(DISTINCT SO_Activity.SO_Activity_Recid) as touches
FROM   v_rpt_Company  
LEFT OUTER JOIN  Company_Team  ON Company_Team.Company_RecID = v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID AND Company_Team.AcctMgr_Flag = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN v_rpt_Member ON v_rpt_Member.Member_RecID = Company_Team.Member_RecID  
LEFT OUTER JOIN SO_Activity ON v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID = SO_Activity.Company_RecID AND ((SO_Activity.Last_Update >= CONVERT(datetime, @date_start, 101)) AND ( SO_Activity.Last_Update <= CONVERT(datetime, @date_end, 101))) 
WHERE v_rpt_Member.Member_ID = @member
Group By v_rpt_Company.Company_Name ) As a 

LEFT OUTER JOIN

(SELECT MAX(SO_Activity.Date_Entered) As lasttouch, v_rpt_Company.Company_Name as name

FROM   v_rpt_Company  
LEFT OUTER JOIN  Company_Team  ON Company_Team.Company_RecID = v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID AND Company_Team.AcctMgr_Flag = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN v_rpt_Member ON v_rpt_Member.Member_RecID = Company_Team.Member_RecID
LEFT OUTER JOIN SO_Activity ON v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID = SO_Activity.Company_RecID

WHERE v_rpt_Member.Member_ID = @member 

GROUP BY v_rpt_Company.Company_Name) as b 

ON a.name = b.name
```

Comment: And is the `COUNT` displaying `NULL` when ther is a value for `Company_name`?, or it does that wen `Company_name` is `NULL`?

Comment: Can you post your table structures as well?

Comment: No, no row is returned for companies with 0 activities. I cannot post table structures, they contain sensitive company data, sorry.

Comment: And do you have a table listing all of your companies somewhere?, otherwise you won't be able to return what you want

Comment: Yes, we have a list of all the companies. It should return all companies where @acctmgr has a acctmgr_flag of 1. Now it only returns rows for companies whose count is >0.

Comment: But you are not using that table (the one with all the companies) on your query, or you are?

Comment: v_rpt_Company is the table with all of the companies. Company_Name is the company name column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

updated: Try this, start with v_rpt_company because you are trying to group by company name.

```
 SELECT       v_rpt_Company.Company_Name, 
COUNT(DISTINCT SO_Activity.SO_Activity_Recid) as touches, 
MAX(SO_Activity.Date_Entered) As lasttouch
FROM   v_rpt_Company  
LEFT OUTER JOIN  Company_Team  ON Company_Team.Company_RecID = v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID AND Company_Team.AcctMgr_Flag = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN v_rpt_Member ON v_rpt_Member.Member_RecID = Company_Team.Member_RecID  
LEFT OUTER JOIN SO_Activity ON v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID = SO_Activity.Company_RecID AND ((SO_Activity.Last_Update >= CONVERT(datetime, @date_start, 101)) AND ( SO_Activity.Last_Update <= CONVERT(datetime, @date_end, 101))) 
WHERE v_rpt_Member.Member_ID = @member 
GROUP BY v_rpt_Company.Company_Name
ORDER BY v_rpt_Company.Company_Name ASC,lasttouch DESC,touches DESC
```

Comment: That returns 0 for every company. But thank you, this is the closest I have gotten.

Comment: can you add schema and 2-3 rows from each table to your question

Comment: It is hard for me to release much data about the tables, I am under an NDA.

Comment: Whenever touches returns 0, lasttouch is blank. Is it not possible to get the lasttouch outside the date range?

Comment: this is not possible based on your date range condition you are using now. Explain more about your requirement in another thread.

Comment: I ended up taking what you had, and created a sub query. check my OP for final.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your count statement like so:

```
COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT SO_Activity.SO_Activity_Recid),0)
```

Comment: No dice. It does not show a row for companies with a 0 count.

Comment: Oh I got you. Your where clause of (Company_Team.AcctMgr_Flag = 1) is going to cause that outer join to not return a record if no rows in Company_Team match the join. Ditto for all other tables being outer joined to that have a where clause. You can add an "OR field is null" to make those joins return rows

Comment: check my post, when you do left outer join and then add a where clause condition to that table column it will not return any null columns

Comment: well..crap. So basically I cannot have a WHERE clause? How do I check if a field is NULL if it does not exist? I can't compare a row that doesn't exist to NULL, can I?

Comment: If no rows are returned from the join, you can still check of the fields are null. Since no rows are returned because the join misses, all fields on that table are null.

Comment: But won't that return companies where acctmgr_flag <> 1?

Comment: You would say where acctmgr_flag is null or acct_mgr_flag = 1. Only would work if acctmgr_flag was never actually null in the table - essentially null is used as a proxy for when the join misses

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with you query:

1. You have conditions in the `WHERE` clause that are going to be false when there's no activity for that company (since values from `SO_Activity` will be null, then conditions will be null too).
2. If the date of last activity can be outside the date range, you need a separate join for that.

Here's the fixed version:

```
SELECT 
v_rpt_Company.Company_Name, 
ISNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT SO_Activity.SO_Activity_Recid), 0) as touches, 
MAX(SO2.Date_Entered) As lasttouch
FROM v_rpt_Member 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Company_Team ON v_rpt_Member.Member_RecID = Company_Team.Member_RecID
LEFT OUTER JOIN v_rpt_Company ON Company_Team.Company_RecID = v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN SO_Activity ON v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID = SO_Activity.Company_RecID
                      AND SO_Activity.Last_Update >= CONVERT(datetime, @date_start, 101) 
                      AND SO_Activity.Last_Update <= CONVERT(datetime, @date_end, 101)
LEFT OUTER JOIN SO_Activity SO2 ON v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID = SO_Activity.Company_RecID
WHERE Company_Team.AcctMgr_Flag = 1 AND v_rpt_Member.Member_ID = @member
GROUP BY v_rpt_Company.Company_Name
ORDER BY v_rpt_Company.Company_Name ASC,lasttouch DESC,touches DESC
```

Comment: This returns all company names, touches always = 0, and lasttouch is always blank.